# In the 2011 film “bad teacher”, there is an exchange between several characters

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, american-english, metaphors, cinema

> **Squirrel:** I am so excited we're gonna be across-the-hall mates. But I'm so sad… it's because your relationship ended.
>   **Elizabeth:** Who are you again?
>   **Squirrel:** Amy Squirrel.
>   **Elizabeth:** Squirrel?
>   **Squirrel:** Yeah, you know. Don't worry, you were… kind of a lone wolf last year and so… busy planning the… wedding…
>   **Elizabeth:** I found him in bed with somebody else.
>   **Squirrel:**  Oh my Gosh!
>   **Elizabeth:** It was a another man.
>   **Squirrel:** Shut the front door! Look… I know you kinda skated by last year, doing the bare minimum thing… but I just wanna say, now you're back, I just know you are gonna get your teaching on.

So what does Squirrel mean by “Don't worry, you were… kind of a lone wolf last year and so… busy planning the… wedding”, and “Look… I know you kinda skated by last year, doing the bare minimum thing”?

Comment: I think she actually says **"kind of a lone wolf last year"**.

Comment: There’s a lot going on here, even within your two excerpts. What parts give you trouble? Do you know what the idiom “lone wolf” means? Do you understand “skated by”? Do you understand “doing the _____ thing”? It may be better to split this into multiple questions that address each separate issue you are having with these constructions, and you may wish to place these questions on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com) instead. In any case, you will get better help if you write a bit about what you do and do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

"Lone wolf" means being solitary and not socializing much.

"Skated by" means that the individual "just got by" or was "on autopilot" or otherwise didn't really work at whatever the task was but simply did the minimum.

"Doing the bare minimum thing" means the same as "skated by".

(And of course "Shut the front door!" is simply an exclamation, similar to "Shut your mouth!" or "You must be kidding!" or "You've got to be kidding!")

(And "get your [something] on" means to get serious about doing [something].)

Comment: More exactly, “shut the front door” is a bowdlerised version of “shut the fuck up”.